# Customer custome attribute value get by customer id in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, customer, customer-attribute, attribute-value

Hi I have custom customer attribute for customer in my magento 1.9.
I want that custom attribute value by customer id.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code....
***If attribute code "myattr" or "my_attr"***

```
$customer_id = 9;
$customer  = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer_id);
$attributeValue  = $customer->getMyattr();// // code is myattr
$attributeValue  = $customer->getMyAttr();// code is my_attr
```